# java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key size DESede encryption

Tags: java, encryption, key, size

I am encrypting string using java "DESede" with 16 bit. I copied code from application which was working fine. But when i tried it is not working. I don't want to change key and encryption

Key in `byte[] key = {-104, 26, -6, -116, -34, -72, -88, -9, -27, -96, 81, -76, 9, -69, 68, -49}`

```
  Key secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(newChar, "DESede");
  Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
  instance.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
```

Error:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong key size
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCrypt.init(DESedeCrypt.java:69)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.ElectronicCodeBook.init(ElectronicCodeBook.java:94)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:591)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:467)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineInit(DESedeCipher.java:166)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:863)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1248)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1185)
```

Comment: DESede requires a 24 byte key.

Comment: Yes i khow that but this application i get code from is using 16byte key and its working fine. How is that possible???

Comment: How is that possible? I have no way to know without seeing the code. There is something called two-key Triple DES that may have been used. Try appending a copy of the first 8 bytes of the key to the end of the 16-byte key, which will give a key of the correct size. See if it works. If it does then the other application is using two key Triple DES.

Comment: Its working on android application fine. I was trying on normal java.